# Prevent iOS webview from scrolling up on keyboard show

Tags: ios, swift

When I select the input box in my webview, the layout scrolls up (see image).

Is there a way to stop the webview from scrolling up?

[image: iOS webview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is webView scrolling and you can detect using scrollViewDelegate method scrollViewDidScroll, You can stop scrolling by using below code.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

   if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 || scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
 }
}
```

Comment: First time hearing about top constraint to be honest. If I understand correct, when I set top constraint it doesn’t scroll up anymore? Am I right?

Comment: @WesleySchravendijk check my updated code, above scrolling method will helps you for stoping the scrolling behaviour of webView.